# How can I execute a curl command in OS process Sampler in jmeter?

Tags: curl, jmeter

How can I execute a curl command in OS process Sampler in jmeter?

I have below command that need to be executed in OS Process Sampler.

curl -k -O http://localhost:9763/filedownload?id=/ushani-com-30786.cert

Please check the attached screenshot and it is not working. What am I doing wrong? Please advice.

[image: OS Process Sampler config]

Comment: Why not using http sampler instead of curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace your `#!/bin/bash` with `/bin/bash`
2. Add `-c` as the first argument

   [image: JMeter Curl OS Process Sampler]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details.

---

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) users are strongly encouraged to use the [latest version of JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider migrating to JMeter 3.3 (or whatever version is available at the [Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

Replace in your `command` field `#!/bin/bash` to `curl`

 and delete `curl` from `command parameters`.

And also add `View Results Tree` listener - so you'll be able to see what `jmeter` trying to execute!